# Dynamic responsive Background Images With WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, dynamic, background-image

Oaky I have question with having dynamic background images that are also responsive.

So what I have done is for a home page, I created a custom image uploader for the main header image so the user can change it for that page. But I want to load the image size based on the screen size with css media queries.

I then created a herostyle.php file and added the following code:

```
<?php

   $absolute_path = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
   $wp_load = $absolute_path[0] . 'wp-load.php';
   require_once($wp_load);


   header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   $heroImage       = get_post_meta( 6, 'main_header_image', true );
   $heroImageFull   = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $heroImage, 'herofull' );
   $heroImageDesk   = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $heroImage, 'herodesk' );
   $heroImageTab    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $heroImage, 'herotab' );
   $heroImageMobile = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $heroImage, 'heromobile' );

?>

.home-hero {
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(<?php echo $heroImageMobile[0]; ?>);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .swb-hero {
        background-image: url(<?php echo $heroImageTab[0]; ?>);
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .swb-hero {
        background-image: url(<?php echo $heroImageDesk[0]; ?>);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    .swb-hero {
        background-image: url(<?php echo $heroImageFull[0]; ?>);
    }
}
```

I then added this stylesheet within my functions.php file with the following code:

```
function my_new_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hero', get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/sass/herostyle.php', null, null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_new_styles' );
```

So what I am doing is the uploaded image is 2400px wide, then I create the four responsive images with WordPress using the following code in my functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'herofull', 2400, 4000, false);
add_image_size( 'herodesk', 1600, 4000, false);
add_image_size( 'herotab', 1000, 4000, false);
add_image_size( 'heromobile', 800, 4000, false);
```

So I guess my question would be, is this good practice just to have the ability for a user to change and an image for backgrounds. I want it to be responsive as well. I would hate to serve a 2400px wide image to a mobile device. If I do this with CSS, then it is not changeable by the user, and I do not want to use inline CSS with PHP for this.

Does anybody know if this has any benefits? Are there better solutions to this issue? The one thing I don't like about this is added another style sheet to the website, should I care?

Thanks for any help/advice on this issue!

Comment: This is the kind of thing that an internal stylesheet is good for. There is nothing wrong with using an internal stylesheet and this is how most of the themes out there allow users to override theme styles with their options. Have a look at `wp_add_inline_style` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style

Comment: awesome, thank you for that quick response. I will have a look at that. What is your thoughts on how I've gone about doing it? Or should I use the WordPress wp_add_inline_style like you suggested?

Comment: I woud use the `wp_add_inline_style` because it gets rid of the extra server request but other than that there is nothing wrong with what you have already done.

Comment: Great! Thank you!